# Graphing A Piecewise Defined Function

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

A question asks to compute 
$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \; dx$$
given a piecewise defined function: 
$$\begin{equation}
    f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
      x, & \text{for}\;\ 0\leq x \leq c \\
      c\dfrac{x-1}{c-1}, & \text{for}\; \ c \leq x \leq 1
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}$$

I know how to integrate it, but then the question asks to draw the graph of $f(x)$, I am confused regarding this part.. how do I graph this exactly? The variable $c$ is what confuses me. It would be very helpful if someone shows me how to graph this.

Comment: Observe that both "pieces" of f are linear, therefore if you know where they begin, and end, you may then join those two points to get the graph. The first piece starts at (0,0) and ends at (c,c). Second piece starts at (c,c) and ends at (1,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x\mapsto x$ is linear, the left part of the graph is just the line segment that goes from $(0,0)$ to $(c,c)$. The map $x\mapsto c\frac{x-1}{c-1}$ is an affine map, So, its graph is a line segment too. Since $c\mapsto c$ and since $1\mapsto 0$, its graph is the line segment from $(c,c)$ to $(1,0)$.

So, you get the broken line that goes from $(0,0)$ to $(c,c)$ and then from $(c,c)$ to $(1,0)$.

Comment: To make sure I understood your point, I tried graphing it on Desmos, here it is: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sgnrdljlrg

Comment: Is that correct? I chose $c=0.9$, however I did notice it would look different if it is $c=0.5$ but it would still look like a triangle

Comment: Yes, it is correct. And it *always* looks like a triangle.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$c$ is a parameter that tells you where the function changes behaviour. Since it's variable, when you draw the graph you pick an arbitrary value of $c$ - the graph still looks quite similar for many valid values of $c$, so just pick one somewhere near $c = 0.5$ and draw that. If the graph *did* change significantly, you might want to draw a few different graphs demonstrating the different behaviours.